# How do I disable partitions from mounting on Lubuntu OS?

Tags: linux, mount, partition, lubuntu

I don't want my Windows NTFS and FAT32 partitions to show on the Linux OS; what is the command to disable them from mounting? I have done it before, but forgot the commands.

Comment: Do you just want to prevent them from being mounted automatically, or do you actually want to prevent PCManFM (the file browser in LXDE) from *showing* them under "Places" and letting you mount them with a single click?

Answer (score 1):

While your distribution will likely still allow automounting those partitions if it mounts them by default they are in `/etc/fstab` .